# What does it mean to "be stunned by boredom and heat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm watching an EX Afghanistan Vet giving a Ted talk. He's talking about how soldiers come to like combat and after going back home, actually miss fighting. This is a sentence that came about during his speech.

"...we haven't seen combat in a couple of weeks and everyone was just completely **stunned with** boredom and heat"

"**stun**"
to shock someone so much that the person does not know how to react:
*She was stunned by his generous offer.*(source:Cambridge Dictionary)

**"stun"**
3. to shock; overwhelm.(source:Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

**"stun"**
3. to surprise or astound(source:Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that has been "stunned" is dizzy or unconscious (especially from a blow to the head).  But in this case the soldiers are dizzy and unable to think clearly as a result of the heat and the boredom.

Comment: Are any of the definitions I provided in the post correct?

Comment: Not quite, the other sense of "stun" is to surprise someone. But the sense here is more like "be knocked out".  Think of Star Trek, and setting the phasers to "stun".  So they knocked-out the enemy without killing them.  In this example it is a bit hyperbolic (they aren't really knocked-out) but this is the basic sense that the speaker is using.